# What is use of @outputCache directive in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, caching, directive

I think it has been related to caching concept but don't know how is it used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read about page output caching on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178597.aspx

The directive allows you to specify settings such as whether a page should have its output cached, for how long, and other configuration options.

Output caching can be a performance benefit to a page that is expensive to run. Once it is cached, future requests will be served from the cache without the page having to run again.

Comment: Dont forget you can also specify OutputCache for a user control. Im sure you know already, just thought id mention so OP knows.